# How does Webpack dev server consume bundle without file in build directory?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have noticed, that when I run `webpack` I have all my bundled files in build directory, but when I run `webpack-dev-server` I don't see them in build directory, nevertheless all is running.

How does WDS manage to do that? 
There are my scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx yarn clean && webpack --mode production",
    "buildRemote": "npx yarn clean && webpack --config webpack.config.remote.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf build",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --quite --no-info"
  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: It keeps them in memory!

Comment: @AlexMichailidis Thanks. Move it to answers, I will tick it as "Solution"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference here is how each method treats webpack's generated assets.

When you run the `webpack` command everything is going to the declared `output.path` via the `fs` module. In other words, generated assets are written to disk.

Now when you run [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server), under the hood [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) kicks in. This is an express middleware that serves webpack's generated assets. Under the hood, it uses [memory-fs](https://github.com/webpack/memory-fs) and as the name suggests this is a file system module that handles everything in javascript objects that being held in memory.